# Pushing AEM content into Solr 6

Tags: java, solr, aem, solrj

I am trying to push the AEM page content to solr remote server. Is there a way we can do it from AEM directly or we have to write a service for it. If I need a service what api should I use. I was able to create solr schema using solrindex node under oak:index.

Thanks

Abhishek

Comment: Hi Abishek, we had a similar requirement and developed an AEM connector, leveraging Adobe's replication framework pushing content to an external search backend such as SOLR. We also implemented a bulk load (or initial load) functionality with the connector. Let me know if you are interested learning more about our connector.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement. When I synced AEM with remote SOLR a separate document was created for each AEM node. So I ended up creating my custom service to bulk load all content pages to solr. I used AEM's query api to extract page content to get id, title, description and path. For description field I did tree traversal to extract property values and created space delimited description text field. I used solrj to then add documents to solr.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Reference links to what Opkar has shared:-

Link:- http://www.aemsolrsearch.com/#/

Git:- https://github.com/headwirecom/aem-solr-search

Video/Demo :- http://www.aemsolrsearch.com/#/demo

AEM 6.2 Documentation :- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/queries-and-indexing.html#Configuring AEM with an embedded SOLR server

Adobe AEM Community post:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__ir8q-is_there_a_detailed.html

I hope this would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni